# How to add a program in registry using batch file?

Tags: batch, windows-registry, cmd.exe

I want to add an `.exe` program to this registry path:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell`

I tried this code

@echo off

reg add  "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v Shell /t REG_SZ /d notepad.exe /f

but not working... please help me.

Comment: [Read, Set or Delete registry keys and values](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html)

Comment: Do you think that `notepad.exe` could become a full scope Windows shell?

Comment: Easiest way to add a key is to manually use Regedit to create the key, then export just that key. This i a .REG file, rather than a .BAT or .EXE, but you can add it via "regedit.exe /S yourfile.reg" in a CMD prompt or BAT file run as Administrator.